# NServiceBus initialization error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nservicebus

After some difficulty I've managed to install NServiceBus 3.2 for the first time and can run the sample applications.

However when I try to create a new project I get the error:

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Patterning.Extensibility.Binding.BindingSerializer' threw an exception.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Pattern Toolkit Builder couldn't not update itself, even after adding credentials in the extension manager.

Going to Internet Explorer->Internet Options->Local Intranet->Sites then unticking Automatically detect intranet network and the 3 other include options allowed the addins to update without requiring credentials.

This allowed the Pattern Toolkit Builder to update correctly and everything worked ok after that.